# Pronunciation of 잘 입다

Tags: pronunciation

I was reading this article (https://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000103&mn_id=95) and it says in one place that it's pronounced 잘립따, but in another it says it's pronounced 자립따. How do you reconcile the two? Also, it says that in general, if a syllable starting in 이, 야, 여, 요, or 유 is preceded by a consonant, even if it's in a different word, then ㄴ or ㄹ is added before it. However, there are exceptions listed later on. Is there any general rule to predict this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

국어사전
http://m.krdic.naver.com/rescript_detail.nhn?seq=1936

**잘 입다**

According to the above link by Naver, the word is pronounced as [자립따] when considering them as two words and [잘립따] when pronouncing them in one sentence.

So if you are uttering a sentence, like: 
이 옷을 되게 잘 입었네!
You pronounce it as [잘립따]